# pause player when going to background and resume when app returns to foreground ios

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

When playing a video in an iOs app I need it to pause when the app is sent to background and resume when the app returns from background.

```
- (void)onApplicationDidBecomeActive:(NSNotification *)notif
{
    NSLog(@"player: app did become active...");
    [self.videoPlayer play];
}
- (void)onApplicationDidEnterBackground:(NSNotification *)notif
{
    NSLog(@"player: app did enter background...");
    [self.videoPlayer pause];
    [self.videoPlayer setFullscreen:NO];

}
```

On iOS7 this works ok but io iOs8 it seems that another player is created underneath the current one. (self.videoPlayer is a MPMoviePlayerController)

Why is this?

Comment: I don't know the answer, some more information may hep me or someone else figure it out. Are you creating the videoPlayer object using Lazy-loading? Is the self object created when the app becomes active or in and possibly adding a second to the app? Perhaps an overview of the main class hierarchy might make things clearer.